# With gitflow, which branch must be on local and which one must be on remote?

Tags: git, workflow, git-flow

I'm going to switch to gitflow ! i'm confused if i should create all branches on remote or there are branches that should be on local !
thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Maria, welcome to SO. I'm afraid your question is too broad to receive any good answers. Maybe check a good tutorial or manual beforehand, or try to narrow your question down to something easier to address?

Comment: usually you only need to create local branches that are of any interest to you. No need to create all branches locally! If you want to create a branch locally and share it with others, you can push new branches to the remote repo as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, all branches exist on the remote repository, since they are public and should be accessible to other developers. Also, the remote repository is where merges take place if you use a repository management framework like `gitlab` or `github`.

When you start to implement a new feature, you will usually check out the `develop` branch (so it needs to exist locally), and start a `feature` branch from there. When you finished implementing your feature, you will want to merge it into the `develop` branch. As I mentioned above, this is usually done after some sort of code review and thus happens on the remote repository, so you will have to push your feature branch there.

The same holds for hotfix branches that you branch off `master`, so you might as well have that one locally.

And you have to create a `release` branch *somewhere*, probably locally, and push it to the remote.

Long story short: As you see, all branches will end up in the remote repository and probably also in your local repository, although not all local branches have to be up to date all the time (you might want to pull changes to `master` only if you plan to create a hotfix on top of them).

Of course, `git` supports all kinds of workflows, and this is by no means mandatory. In the end it's up to you, but in my experience it mostly ends up as I described above.

Comment: All branches are public? What do you mean?

Comment: @kowsky thank you. But if we don't use the merge request, it's possible to merge locally no ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox "public" might not be the right word here. I mean that you want every contributor to your repository to be able to check out your `develop` and `master` branches.

Comment: @marialopez Yes, if you do not use code review mechanisms like merge or pull requests, you can merge locally and the remote repostory might never see your `feature` branch, you will just push to develop, to which you merged the commits of your feature. Although not doing code reviews and pushing directly to devlop are genereally considered bad practice.